# Same function to create DataTables with different content

Tags: datatables

I have a custom defined function in my jQuery that creates a DataTable exactly how I want. I want to extend it so that different data is displayed depending on the parameter passed to this function. Certain button click on the DOM will call this custom function providing the required parameters. Code for review:

```
function myFunction(inpData) {
       $('#element').DataTable({ 
        // code here successfully draws the table as required
        });
}

$('#div-a').on('click', 'button',function() {
var altdata = 'altData'; 
    $('#element').children().remove(); // not sure if this is required
    myFunction(altData);
});
```

Doing so is resulting in unable to initialise table error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using 'fnClearTable' to clear table and then add data.

Comment: from where you get the data?

Comment: @inye data is received as JSON via an ajax call ; the data is an array of JSON objects

Answer (score 0):

worked it out ; just required the use of "destroy":true